# How to run Apache Tomcat 8 in debug mode?

Tags: jvm, remote-debugging, tomcat8, jpda, jdwp

I am trying to run Apache Tomcat 8.0.21 in debug mode.

When I give the command

```
sh catalina.sh jpda start
```

it gives this error.

**error message**

> ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command
>   line for duplicate jdwp options. Error occurred during initialization
>   of VM agent library failed to init: jdwp

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Are you using this option as well in Java options : -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y ? If yes, no need to start tomcat with jpda (sh catalina.sh jpda start), start it without the jpda option.

Comment: Yes. I'm using that method.

Comment: Please don't use jpda while starting tomcat then.

Answer (score 10):

**Either**

```
unset CATALINA_OPTS
unset JPDA_ADDRESS
unset JPDA_OPTS
unset JPDA_TRANSPORT

catalina.sh jpda start
```

**Or**

```
# in .bashrc, .profile etc.
export CATALINA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Denv=dev -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=768m"

# At your shell prompt
./startup.sh
```

---

*Explanation*

As Arnab said in the comments, if your shell configuration includes environment variables mentioning jdpw (such as `CATALINA_OPTS`, `JDPA_ADDRESS`, `JPDA_OPTS`), just launch using `./startup.sh` as if you were not trying to do remote debugging and the script will pick up the jdpw option from your environment variables.

The launch option syntax `catalina.sh jpda start` should only be used if you don't have any environment variables that already specified a remote debug port. It's meant to be convenient but if you've previously configured your shell to support java remote debugging you're probably mixing the two alternative approaches.

Answer (score 8):

You can just add env variable and run the tomcat as usual

**Debug port is 8000** in this case

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Then run the tomcat

```
sh ./catalina.sh start
```

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me **with Eclipse** when I tried to add the debugging parameters (-Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y) so I could suspend Tomcat on start.  Unfortunately I then launched my Tomcat (within Eclipse) using the Debug button.

**Why this is a problem**
When you are launching Tomcat in Debug mode Eclipse itself inserts the debug parameters. When you have your own debug parameters in the launch configuration you are indeed passing them twice.

So if you need to launch Tomcat from within Eclipse and suspend it on start (so you can connect with debugger) you need to:
 - add the debugging parameters to the "Arguments -> VM arguments" box of your launch config,
 - and then **Run** this config, not Debug.
This way only the debugging parameters from your launch config are added.

Answer (score 2):

There is alternative approach, recommended in 'catalina.sh':

"Do not set the variables in this script. Instead put them into a script 
**setenv.sh** in CATALINA_BASE/bin to keep your customizations separate."

For Windows, the file name with environment variables will be 'setenv.bat'.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mr Dimitar II
Verified this works perfectly and is consumed automatically when running startup.bat
file: setenv.bat

```
@echo off
rem The proper way to set environment up for running Catalina
set "CATALINA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```